# How do I call "CoInitializeSecurity" before an c# application to deactivate COM-Security?

Tags: c#, wpf, bluetooth, com

I've written an WPF-Apllication in c#, that uses Bluetooth Low Energy. The values of the BLE-device are never received by the app and googeling the problem suggests COM-Security may be the problem.

To solve that problem, the following website:

http://microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/58da3fdb-a0e1-4161-8af3-778b6839f4e1/bluetooth-bluetoothledevicefromidasync-does-not-complete-on-10015063?forum=wdk

...suggested to call [CoInitializeSecurity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms693736(v=vs.85).aspx) manually before the c# programm starts (since when the c# program starts, the function would be called implicitly and you can't call it twice).

Sadly I have no idea how to call this function, if I can't call it from my c#-sourcecode.

Any help highly appreciated!

**EDIT:**
http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/ole32.coinitializesecurity is the best help I found so far and they state "The workaround is to write an unmanaged "shim" that will call CoInitializeSecurity, then activate and call into managed code. You can do this via an export from a mixed-mode C++ DLL, by registering a managed component for use by COM, or by using the CLR hosting API." I have absolutely no idea what these things mean.

Comment: Or you could just install the windows update that fixes the problem: "This issue has been fixed and is available in the latest Windows Insider Fast program flights.  If you are willing, you can validate that this resolves you issues by enrolling into the insider program and installing the latest Fast flight available.  The issue was also rolled out and serviced via Windows Update at the end of June, but is currently an optional update that requires manual installation."

Comment: @LynnCrumbling I did that on my private computer (and then everything works fine), but can't do that on my work-pc. And I can't expect all my customers to do that either.

Comment: @murkr I am having the exact same problem. Did you ever figure it out? That would be huge help.

Comment: @JayJacobs yeah, sorry we fixed it and it was a bitch. The official windows forum (I'm afraid it was at the link I listed below - and doesn't work anymore) they showed how to write a file "*.reg* which rewrites the windows registry. Sorry that I can't give more specific help, it's such a long time ago.

Answer (score 1):

I hit the same problem, and I resolved it by adding CoInitializeSecurity in App constructor.

App.xaml.cs

```
public partial class App : Application
{
   App()
    {
      CoInitializeSecurity(IntPtr.Zero, -1, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, RpcAuthnLevel.Default, RpcImpLevel.Impersonate, IntPtr.Zero, EoAuthnCap.StaticCloaking, IntPtr.Zero);
    }
}
```