# C# code Restore Point does not show the restore point supposedly created in System Restore

Tags: c#, restore, point

Thanks for reading this message.

I have the following code in a C# form with a button:

```
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct RESTOREPOINTINFO
        {
            public int dwEventType;
            public int dwRestorePtType;
            public Int64 llSequenceNumber;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 257)]
            public string szDescription;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct STATEMGRSTATUS
        {
            public uint nStatus;
            public Int64 llSequenceNumber;
        }

        [DllImport("SrClient.dll")]
        public static extern bool SRSetRestorePoint(ref RESTOREPOINTINFO SRPInfo, ref STATEMGRSTATUS SRPStatus);

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Open the registry key for System Restore
            RegistryKey SystemRestoreKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\SystemRestore", true);

            // Disable automatic creation of restore points
            SystemRestoreKey.SetValue("SystemRestorePointCreationFrequency", 0, RegistryValueKind.DWord);

            bool result = false;
            RESTOREPOINTINFO RPInfo = new RESTOREPOINTINFO();
            STATEMGRSTATUS RPStatus = new STATEMGRSTATUS();

            // Set the restore point information
            RPInfo.dwEventType = 100;
            RPInfo.dwRestorePtType = 0;
            RPInfo.llSequenceNumber = 0;
            RPInfo.szDescription = "System Restore Point";

            // Create the restore point
            result = SRSetRestorePoint(ref RPInfo, ref RPStatus);

            // Delete the SystemRestorePointCreationFrequency value from the registry key
            SystemRestoreKey.DeleteValue("SystemRestorePointCreationFrequency");

            // Display a message indicating whether the restore point was created successfully or not
            if (result)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("System restore point created successfully.", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Failed to create system restore point.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
    }
```

I run the program with Administrator permissions, because otherwise I receive an operation message not allowed by security policy.

All right. I click on the button and supposedly the restore point is created, because I see the hard drive working and the restore point successfully created message appears on the screen.

But when I go to System Restore in Control Panel, the Restore Point I just created is not found.

"Volume Shadow Copy Service error: Unexpected error querying the IVssWriterCallback interface. HR = 0x80070005, Access Denied.
. It often occurs due to incorrect security settings in the write or request process."

and

"Volume Shadow Copy Service error: Unexpected error calling routine QueryFullProcessImageNameW. HR = 0x80070006, Invalid Controller."

I have also read that for the Restore Point to be created, the System would have to be restarted. I don't know if that's the problem, or how I could fix it.

Can anyone offer me some code that works correctly today?

Thanks.

I have already tried several codes, and I can't find any that performs a Restore Point correctly in a form project.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46405530/how-do-i-call-coinitializesecurity-before-an-c-sharp-application-to-deactivate