# Error accessing COM object with impersonation

Tags: c#, iis, com, impersonation

I have a .NET 6 web application running on IIS 7, and I need to impersonate the current user to submit a certificate request on their behalf.

I have configured the Claims to Windows Token service (c2wts) to allow the application pool identity to impersonate users, and I have granted the group `IIS_IUSRS` the "impersonate a client after authentication" privilege from the local security policies console.

Impersonation seems to work properly, e.g. this method returns the expected result:

```cs
public string TestImpersonation(string currentUserUpn) {
    var identity = new WindowsIdentity(currentUserUpn);
    return WindowsIdentity.RunImpersonated(identity.AccessToken, () => {
        return WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
    });
}
```

However, when I try to instantiate a COM object I get an error. For example this code

```cs
// Requires
// using Interop.CERTCLILib;

public int SubmitRequest(
    string currentUserUpn,
    string certificateSigningRequest,
    string certificateTemplate,
    string caConfiguration) {

    var identity = new WindowsIdentity(currentUserUpn);
    return WindowsIdentity.RunImpersonated(identity.AccessToken, () => {
        ICertRequest request = new CCertRequest();
        RequestEncoding requestEncoding = RequestEncoding.CR_IN_BASE64HEADER | RequestEncoding.CR_IN_FORMATANY;
        int disposition = request.Submit(
            Flags: requestEncoding,
            strRequest: certificateSigningRequest,
            strAttributes: $"CertificateTemplate: {certificateTemplate}",
            strConfig: caConfiguration);
        return request.GetRequestId();
    });
}
```

produces this exception:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Interop.CERTCLILib, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. Either a required impersonation level was not provided, or the provided impersonation level is invalid. (0x80070542)

I tried calling explicitly

```cs
CoInitializeEx(IntPtr.Zero, COINIT.APARTMENTTHREADED | COINIT.DISABLE_OLE1DDE);
```

but nothing changed.

Is there anything else I should look into?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46405530/how-do-i-call-coinitializesecurity-before-an-c-sharp-application-to-deactivate

Comment: Refer to this Support Blog: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-support-blog/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-enterpriseservices/ba-p/317076.